# Why does the Torah tell us the previous name of Bethel?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, vayeitzei, cities

[Beraishis 28 (19)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> He named that site Bethel; but previously the name of the city had
>   been Luz.

Why does the Torah tell us the previous name of Bethel? There must be something the Torah wants us to know.

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0701.htm#22

Comment: @Avrohom-Yitzchok or to anybody, what is the proximity or relation of Bethel to "Sukkot" (Genesis 33:17)? Is it the same place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Rabeinu Bachya [there](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28?lang=bi&aliyot=0) who says it hints to resurrection and rejuvenation.

> ואולם לוז שם העיר לראשונה. המקום שקראו בית אל והוא ירושלים, מה היה הצורך להודיענו שנקרא לוז מתחילה ומה תועלת המגעת אלינו מזה. ויתכן לומר כי בא הכתוב לרמוז לנו בשם הזה כי מזה התחיל העולם להשתכלל ולהתחדש, והנה הוא ראשית הבריאה והחדוש, וע"כ גלה לנו כי שם העיר לראשונה לוז מלשון לוז השדרה באדם, שממנו עתיד להתנער ולהתחדש ולהברא לתחיית המתים, כי כשם שפלא החדוש הזה היה משם כך פלא של תחיית המתים יתחיל משם, וכבר באר דוד המלך ע"ה הענין הזה ואמר כי בריאת הארץ גם בריאת הנפש והגוף הכל מהאמצעית היא ציון. וזהו שאמר (תהילים נ׳:א׳) אל אלהים ה' דבר ויקרא ארץ וגו'. (שם) מציון מכלל יופי וגו', (שם) יקרא אל השמים מעל וגו'.
>
> ואולם לוז שם העיר לראשונה
> “however, the name of this town used to be Luz.”
> The place they called Bet El at that time is Jerusalem now. Why did the Torah bother to tell us that at a still earlier point in history the town had been known as Luz? What benefit do we derive from such information? Perhaps the Torah wanted to hint that the name Luz had been the starting point of the earth rejuvenating itself. It was the site at which earth first started to develop into the globe as we know it. The words לוז השדרה, (Vayikra Rabbah 18,1) mean the place in the spine from which the tissue is able to regenerate itself at the time of the resurrection. Just as the coming into existence of the physical universe out of nothing was something miraculous, so the resurrection when it occurs will be a miracle of similar dimensions. King David had already alluded to this phenomenon when he described the creation of soul, body as well as the eventual resurrection as originating in the “centre” called Zion. He phrased it thus in Psalms 3, 1-3: אל אלוקים ה' דבר, ויקרא ארץ ממזרח שמש עד מבואו. מציון מכלל יופי אלוקים הופיע.
> “G’d the Lord spoke and summoned the world from east to west.. From Zion, perfect in beauty, G’d appeared.”

*From Sefaria*